# Cannot Serialize interface

Tags: wcf

This is my ABC on the server side:

```
<endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\imhmsgs" 
          binding="msmqIntegrationBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="IncomingMessageHandlerBinding" 
         contract="TMC.Services.Contracts.Messages.IInboundMessageHandlerService">
```

As soon as I do an `.Open()` to host the service, I get the exception:

> Cannot serialize interface
>   XYZ.Services.Contracts.Messages.Interfaces.IMyMessage.

My IMyMessage interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(IMyMessage))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ConcreteMessage))]
public interface IInboundMessageHandlerService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void ProcessIncomingMessage(MsmqMessage<IMyMessage> incomingMessage); 
}
```

The implementor for that interface:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
                 ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false)]
public class InboundMessageHandlerService : IInboundMessageHandlerService
{
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    public void ProcessIncomingMessage(MsmqMessage<IMyMessage> incomingMessage)
    {
    }
 }
```

The type that is being created by the client basically is a concrete class, which derives from a base class and also an interface (IMyMessage) and then places this on the MSMQ.

After some testing, if I remove the service known type attributes and just instead use say "string" instead, then it seems to open the host but faults (because the message type is not what it was expecting).

where am I going wrong?

On further testing I see that if I only specify the concrete type, it works.

This is not quite what I was expecting.
how am I able to create it so that the service can take a known interface and classes which that interface has? The idea is for the client (using the same contract and classes) to send the message as "IMyMessage" and for the WCF service to pick that up as "IMyMessage" and go ahead and find out the type of message/object it is.

How?

Comment: Checkout this thread [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ff81b538-939e-4acf-bef3-40d3677f2f1d].  It seems like a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. unfortunately that link does not work for me however I think I managed to do it here. Instead of using an interface, just use a base class instead and serialize/pass that to the WCF service, which then has that as the expected parameter but make sure that the service is decorated with all possible known types that derive from the base class. This seems to work perfectly (for now!)

Comment: actually for some bizarre reason. it works the way I wanted to in the first place.... not sure why or how. *scratches head*... so client created concrete classes which are derived from a base from which implements an interface. Client sends the class of the interface type - WCF picks it up no problem and we can check the type of concrete class it is. Maybe I added the known types in the base class perhaps which made it "work" - I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your contract is an interface, but the definition within the contract must be concrete classes.

In your case it looks like you want to send over a list of things, those things could be different but they all support the same interface.

The problem is that when WCF deserialises what has been sent over the wire, it needs to deserialise it the a concrete type. If it just has an interface in the definition and 20 different types that implement that definition, it does not know what to do with it.

What you can do is have a base type that implements the interface, all your classes inherit from the base type and you use the base type in your contact.

Comment: Thanks. yes, this is how I got it working before it was "broken" but now its magically "fixed"....

Comment: another type of project is in the works however its structured differently. All concrete classes has its own base class. all base classes derive from 1 main base class. The base and concrete classes are seperate projects. I can send a concrete message to the queue but WCF fails to deserialize. The service contract takes in a base class as the parameter (mainbase). There are no service operations since these are just data classes (has datacontract attribs). Any ideas where I am going wrong here? Where should I declare knowntypes? Would these also be of all base types?